# AWS boto3 Athena query results are not saving to local path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-athena

I am trying to run a simple athena query and trying to save the results to a local path.

```
response = athena.start_query_execution(
    QueryString='select query',
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': 'test'
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': r'C:\Projects\Project0\'
    }
```

But I am getting the below error.

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidRequestException: An error occurred
>   (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution
>   operation: outputLocation is not a valid S3 path.

Is it possible to save the results to local path? I couldnt find any information in boto3 docs.

Answer (score 2):

ResultConfiguration does not contain the result of your query. You have to make a second call using 'QueryExecutionId' and the `get_query_results` function:

```
exe = athena.start_query_execution(
    QueryString='select query',
    QueryExecutionContext={
        'Database': 'test'
    },
    ResultConfiguration={
        'OutputLocation': 's3 location'
    }
result = athena.get_query_results(
    QueryExecutionId=exe['QueryExecutionId']
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Athena results only can be saved to s3 location.Please refer to [OutputLocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_ResultConfiguration.html#athena-Type-ResultConfiguration-OutputLocation) to know more about the semantics.If you want this result in your local system then you can go to the s3 location which you have provided as input to your start_query_execution API call and download result from s3 console or use [aws s3 cp command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)